# Create grid with configurable items

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-grid

I try to create a grid system with configurable items to set position and size.
The problem is, the height/width setting has no affect on the gird items. They remain all the same size as 1x1, and the first item does not take up 2x1:

```js
const items = [{
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    w: 2,
    h: 1
}, {
    x: 2,
    y: 2,
    w: 1,
    h: 1
}, {
    x: 3,
    y: 3,
    w: 1,
    h: 1
}];



document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {

    let numCols = 3;
    let numRows = 3;

    let gridContainer = document.getElementById("grid-container");


    gridContainer.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${numCols}, 1fr)`;
    gridContainer.style.gridTemplateRows = `repeat(${numRows}, 1fr)`;


    items.forEach((obj, i) => {

        let elem = document.createElement("div");

        elem.classList.add("grid-item");
        elem.textContent = `#${i} - ${obj.x}, ${obj.y}`;

        // Set the position dynamically
        elem.style.gridRow = `${obj.x} / span ${obj.w}`;
        elem.style.gridColumn = `${obj.y} / span ${obj.h}`;

        gridContainer.appendChild(elem);

    });

});
```

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#grid-container {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  /*gap: 1px; /* Optional: Add gap between grid items */
}

.grid-item {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Full-Height Grid System</title>
  
</head>
<body>

  <div id="grid-container"></div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Why is the width setting for the first element ignored?

Actual result:
[image]

Wanted result:
[image]

Comment: Add a `console.log(elem)` before appending and you'll see the problem. The first div is not receiving any inline styles. Check my answer for the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## You made two mistakes.

### First mistake:

First off, you cannot set `grid-row-start: 0;` (same for column), which is why the inline styles are not even being applied to your first `div`. The numbers must be non-zero integers.

So for your first item, instead of

```js
{ x: 0, y: 0; w: 2, h: 1 }
```

it has to be

```js
{ x: 1, y: 1; w: 2, h: 1 }
```

### Second mistake:

You're using the wrong parameters for row and column, you need to exchange those:

```js
elem.style.gridRow = `${obj.x} / span ${obj.w}`;
elem.style.gridColumn = `${obj.y} / span ${obj.h}`;
```

should be

```js
elem.style.gridRow = `${obj.x} / span ${obj.h}`;
elem.style.gridColumn = `${obj.y} / span ${obj.w}`;
```

```js
const items = [{
    x: 1,
    y: 1,
    w: 2,
    h: 1
}, {
    x: 2,
    y: 2,
    w: 1,
    h: 1
}, {
    x: 3,
    y: 3,
    w: 1,
    h: 1
}];



document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {

    let numCols = 3;
    let numRows = 3;

    let gridContainer = document.getElementById("grid-container");


    gridContainer.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${numCols}, 1fr)`;
    gridContainer.style.gridTemplateRows = `repeat(${numRows}, 1fr)`;


    items.forEach(({x,y,w,h}, i) => {

        let elem = document.createElement("div");

        elem.classList.add("grid-item");
        elem.textContent = `#${i} - x:${x}, y:${y}, w:${w}, h:${h}`;

        // Set the position dynamically
        elem.style.gridRow = `${x} / span ${h}`;
        elem.style.gridColumn = `${y} / span ${w}`;

        gridContainer.appendChild(elem);

    });

});
```

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#grid-container {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  /*gap: 1px; /* Optional: Add gap between grid items */
}

.grid-item {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid-container"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const items = [{
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    w: 2,
    h: 1
  },
  {
    x: 2,
    y: 2,
    w: 1,
    h: 1
  },
  {
    x: 3,
    y: 3,
    w: 1,
    h: 1
  }
];

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {

  let numCols = 4; // Adjusted for item spanning 2 columns
  let numRows = 4; // Adjusted for item spanning 1 row

  let gridContainer = document.getElementById("grid-container");

  gridContainer.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${numCols}, 1fr)`;
  gridContainer.style.gridTemplateRows = `repeat(${numRows}, 1fr)`;

  items.forEach((obj, i) => {
    let elem = document.createElement("div");
    elem.classList.add("grid-item");
    elem.textContent = `#${i} - ${obj.x}, ${obj.y}`;

    // Set position and size dynamically
    elem.style.gridColumn = `${obj.x}`;
    elem.style.gridRow = `${obj.y}`;
    elem.style.gridColumnEnd = `span ${obj.w}`;
    elem.style.gridRowEnd = `span ${obj.h}`;

    gridContainer.appendChild(elem);
  });
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#grid-container {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  /*gap: 1px; /* Optional: Add gap between grid items */
}

.grid-item {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Full-Height Grid System</title>

</head>

<body>

  <div id="grid-container"></div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

use `grid-column-end` and `grid-row-end` to set item dimensions and
adjust `numCols` and `numRows` to match the maximum spans in the items array